# Laravel blade pass data back to included components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've created some simple form components for laravel that show forms the way i like. Now i what to prepend to each of them another component that makes some operations to set some defaults, but i haven't understood how to pass data back from the included component.

Here's an example, here's the helper `helper.blade.php`

```
if (!isset($label)) $label = $name;

if (!isset($label_attributes)) $label_attributes = [];
$label_attributes['for'] = $name;
if (!isset($label_attributes['class'])) $label_attributes['class'] = 'col-md-2';
```

Now i want this code to be executed inside the `text.blade.php` component, but when i call

```
@include('components.form.helper');
{{ Form::label($name, $label, $label_attributes) }}
```

the code inside `helper` is executed, but the `$label_attributes` is not passed back to `text.blade.php` since i got the error `Undefined variable: label_attributes`

How can i pass data back?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using @extends in your content layout you can use this:

```
@extends('master', ['title' => $title])
```

if you wanna user include you can use it like this way :

```
@include('views.otherView', ['variable' => 1])
```

Comment: The problem is not in passing the value *to* the inner components, as in your example, but in passing *back* the parameters. I have the variables that have to be set in `helper.blade` which have to be passed back `text.blade`